# Browser Error in Console. => Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:56997/

Tags: reactjs, websocket, browser

I am building a fullstack project in vscode. but I am getting this error on every browser consoles. and this error keeps coming repeatedly:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:56997/.a1aw

How can this be fixed?

I am not using any websocket config.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (the steps to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: acutally it's difficult to provide any piece of code. Here's an image link of how it looks in browser when I run local server.
https://prnt.sc/IPXlhh2Yxp7W